# IPhone Geocoding

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-maps, iphone-sdk-3.0, google-maps-api-3

There is absolutely no tutorials on geocoding on the iphone. Only reverse geocoding. I have an address, want to convert to coordinates, then display a streetview of that address. How can this be accomplished...

**EDIT**

The below answer pretty much echos what I found online, but I know this can be accomplished using Googles JSON geocoding. I am working on this now, will update post when I figure out how to pull out the coordinates.

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="+ address+"&key="+apiKey+"&sensor=false&output=json"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

built in forward geocoding is new to iOS5. look at CLGeocoder, which includes methods like `geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:`. if you want to support pre-iOS5 then you'll have to use another service, e.g. google's. i haven't used it myself, but a quick search turned up: https://github.com/mjisrawi/iOS-Geocoding-Services  which may be of use.